# How to get a nonzero Zak phase?

Tags: condensed-matter

I try to calculate and obtain a non-zero Zak phase in a system with a winding number of $1$, but the result is always $0$, why?
The Hamiltonian reads
\begin{equation}
H=\vec{n}\cdot \sigma=(\sin k,0,-\cos k)\cdot (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos k & \sin k\\
\sin k & \cos k
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $k$ is a wave vector in $1$BZ. The eigenvector belonging to the eignevalue $\lambda=-1$ is
\begin{equation}
\lvert u_{-1}\rangle=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \frac{k}{2} \\
-\sin \frac{k}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The winding number of this model is simple:
\begin{equation}
\omega=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-\partial_k \cos k}{\sin k} dk=1.
\end{equation}
According to the paper in  10.1103/RevModPhys.82.1959, the Zak phase
\begin{equation}
\gamma_n=i\int_{BZ}\langle u_{-1}\lvert \partial_k \rvert u_{-1}\rangle dk=0.
\end{equation}
Does a zak phase of $0$ mean that it contradicts a non-zero winding number?

Comment: Where does that paper claim that the Zak phase vanishes?

Comment: I may not have written clearly enough for the above question.  I use the formula in [link] ( 10.1103/RevModPhys.82.1959) to calculate the Zak phase  of this model and the result is $0$. I don't know why.